# Filter by date in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a date column (DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss) as follows:

```
02/09/2021 09:50:37
03/09/2021 09:20:27
02/09/2021 14:05:25
03/09/2021 12:50:28
02/09/2021 14:25:26
```

What's the most efficient way to filter by date?

Note: I tried with

```
select date 
from table
where date = '02/09/2021'
```

However, this provides results that wrongly lack the time and only contain the date 02/09/2021.

For example, 02/09/2021 09:50:37 would not be returned.

Comment: `where date >= '02/09/2021' AND date < '03/09/2021'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple option is

```
select * 
from your_table
where trunc(date_column) = date '2021-09-02'
```

If there's an index on `date_column`, it wouldn't be used in that case so performance might suffer so you'll have to either create a function-based index, or use a different `where` clause:

```
where date_column >= date '2021-09-02' and date_column < date '2021-03-03'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return every record that has some date column equal to some date regardless to the time part then you need this:

```
select date 
from table
where trunc(date) = '02/09/2021'
```

please avoid naming columns date and tables table.
[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8b112a45183a835024f876df3ed09901)

Answer (score 1):

Use a date range:

```sql
SELECT date_column
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_column >= DATE '2021-09-02'
AND    date_column <  DATE '2021-09-02' + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

This will enable Oracle to use an index on the `date_column` column.

If you filter using:

- `TRUNC(date_column) = DATE '2021-09-02'` or
- `TO_CHAR(date_column, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = '02-09-2021'`

Then Oracle will not use an index on the `date_column` and would need a separate function-based index on either `TRUNC(date_column)` or `TO_CHAR(date_column, 'DD-MM-YYYY')`.